# How do I detect kubernetes cluster provider (eks, aks) in helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, amazon-eks, kubernetes-helm

I want to write a generic helm chart that would work across all providers of kubernetes platfrom - Azure aks, AWS eks. There is at least one difference that I need to handle - AWS eks does not support sessionAffinity as part of Service spec.

What is the best way to (automatically) detect the kubernetes platfrom so that such differences can be handled? I can always ask the user to provide that as an input but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

For EKS you could use Helm Capabilities, because it seems that EKS appends a `-eks` to the GitVersion of Kubernetes clusters.

You can see that with `kubectl version`.

In Helm here is documented how to read the GitVersion value:

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/

You template code should look like this:

```
{{- if not (.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion | contains "-eks") }}
       
( specific EKS lines here )     

{{- end }}
```

The same is for GKE:

```
{{- if not (.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion | contains "-gke") }}
       
( specific GKE lines here )     

{{- end }}
```

For AKS you cannot do this, because `kubectl version` returns a `GitVersion` that is the standard SemVer version, for example: `v1.25.2`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cloud providers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/) document on Kubernetes, “The in-tree cloud providers typically need both --cloud-provider and --cloud-config specified in the command lines for the kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and the kubelet”. So, if you can query those values you can be able to achieve what you want.